how to apply sort query with lower() without touching BE?
i have spring as BE,POSTGRESQL and Vue 3 composition api setup as FE. in my Vue i used datatable
the problem is, when i want to sort data. the uppercase and lowercase is separated like A,B,C...Z,a,b,c..z. from BE i used PAGEABLE from import org.springframework.data.domain.Pageable;  so i dont want to touch the BE.
my FE:
const response = await databaseService.retrieve(
                {
                    criteriaQuery: query,
                    paginationQuery: {
                        page: params.current_page - 1,
                        size: params.pagesize,
                        sort: [`${params.sort_column},${params.sort_direction}`],
                    },
                },
                apiUOM
            );
            items.value = await response.data;

databaseService.retrieve:
public retrieve(query?: IRetrieveParameter, apiUrl?: string): Promise<any> {
        const url = apiUrl || this.baseApiUrl;
        return new Promise<any>(async (resolve, reject) => {
            let queryParams = buildPaginationQueryOpts(query?.paginationQuery);

            if (query?.criteriaQuery) {
                if (queryParams.length) {
                    queryParams += '&';
                }
                queryParams += buildCriteriaQueryString(query.criteriaQuery);
            }
            const config: any = {};
            if (query?.abortController) {
                config.signal = query.abortController.signal;
            }
            await axiosInstance
                .get(`${url}?${queryParams}`, config)
                .then(function (res) {
                    resolve(res);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                    if (err.code === 'ERR_NETWORK') {
                        router.push('/serverError');
                    } else if (err.response.status === 401) {
                        router.push('/unauthorize');
                    }
                    reject(err);
                });
        });
    }

What I want to know is, is it possible to achieve the sorting without modifying the backend, but still ensure that the result is not divided by lowercase and uppercase?

In ASCII/UTF-8, A-Z  (65-90) come before a-z (97-122) in value. That's probably why they get sorted like that. There should be an argument that takes in a sorting function that allows you to sort them differently in backend, and you should still be able to use Pageable. I would focus there. Unless you retrieve all pages on the frontend, you won't be able to recreate the whole datatable correctly sorted and paginated.

Unless the database is trivially small, you should start by looking at the collations of the columns you wish to sort in a case-insensitive manner so that they’re sorted in this way in the database
